# Spark performance a large data-set save from Dataframe to hdfs or hive

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I have a large dataset in Spark Dataframe. I want to save this data into hive. Which of the following option will give me the best performance?

- Save this data from SPARK Dataframe to hdfs and create Hive external
  table on top of it?
- Write the data from SPARK Dataframe to Hive table
  directly?

Which one will give the best performance and why?

Comment: I can't see too much difference between them. No matter which way you use, spark writes data into hdfs file and let the hive catalog load new metadata.

Answer (score -1):

It's better to Write the data from SPARK Dataframe to Hive table directly.

**All data stored in Hive tables are stored as files in HDFS.**

Saving the data in HDFS and creating an Hive external table on top of it seems to be a double work.

And Spark has the feature of saving the data present in a dataframe directly to a Hive table provided you have to create a hive table with the schema which is in dataframe which is a lot easier.

Performance of Spark in writing data from dataframe to hdfs or Hive table depends on the Cluster setup you have.